# How to get dynamic data into array KingFisher swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dynamic, kingfisher

I newbie swift IOS .. i used this kingfisher to get image from url ..

This is original code ..

```
let kingfisherSource = [KingfisherSource(urlString:"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1432679963831-2dab49187847?w=1080")!, KingfisherSource(urlString: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1447746249824-4be4e1b76d66?w=1080")!, KingfisherSource(urlString: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1463595373836-6e0b0a8ee322?w=1080")!]
```

I have dynamic data .. such maybe the url can be one , or can be two or many ..

how can i get code like this one

```
let kingfisherSource = [KingfisherSource(urlString:"url[0]")!, KingfisherSource(urlString: "url[1]")!, KingfisherSource(urlString: "url[2]")!]
```

This is my code .. but i dont know to get like above..

```
for index in 0 ..< self.orderAttemptImageArray.count        {
    print(orderAttemptImageArray[index].mUrl!)

         var kingfisherSource = [KingfisherSource(urlString: "\(orderAttemptImageArray[index].mUrl!)")!]

    }
```

Please help me ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First init an array of KingfisherSource type like that

```
var items = [KingfisherSource]()
```

Then do what you did earlier & append each kingfisherSource object in items array.

```
for index in 0 ..< self.orderAttemptImageArray.count{
   var kingfisherSource = KingfisherSource(urlString: "\(orderAttemptImageArray[index].mUrl!)")! as! KingfisherSource
   items.append(kingfisherSource)
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks .. but i got error at items.append(kingfisherSource).. cant convert value of type [KingFisherSources] to expected argument type 'KingfisherSources'